# spring mvc file upload is not working in gradle

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-security, gradle

spring mvc file upload is not working correctly , i am getting the following error while uploading the file

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:350)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:139)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:883)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:380)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

added the multipart resolver in the context file and attached commons.io-2.4.jar ,commons-fileuploader-1.2.jar s, i am unable to find the where its failed.. please suggest me the solution, i am using gradle to build the project. if i remove multipart resolver in context.xml the error is not comming but unable to get the uploaded file

Comment: recheck if [CommonsIO] http://commons.apache.org/io/  is available in your class path.

Comment: @DarshanPatel, checked it correctly. uploaded from there only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

commons io is the problem here
removed the commons-io jar file and clean build the module its working fine now

Answer (score -1):

Can you use maven to resolve dependency. Looks like some issue with your dependency resolve.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i am not using maven , i am using gradle so that i attached the commons-io jar files to it

Comment: @Satish - Got it. Let me check.

Comment: @ABP Darshan Patel commented to check for availability of io jar in Class. Without confirmation u answerd.

Comment: @Satish - Do you have commons-logging.jar in your class path ? I think this is also required

Comment: Please could you post your build.gradle?  Maybe we can scratch something from there

Comment: @ABP , i am having it commons-logging-1.1.1.jar and commons-logging-api-1.1.jar files

Comment: @Satish : Okey. Just another point, make sure by mistake you do not have 2 versions of commons.io-.jar

Comment: @Satish :If you find the solution please update here so that other can be helped !